# r - creating dummy columns of U.S. regions from a single states column

Tags: r, for-loop, gis

I have been working with a data set that has a single column of states with 3,000 observations. In order to run a neural network I was attempting to dummy code the states into region columns including pacific, central, eastern, AK, HI, and mountain.

The following code works but I feel like there must be an easier way.

Packages installed:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(FNN)
library(rpart)
library(C50)
library(nnet)
library(FME)
```

The for loop I have been using.

```
    for (i in 1:length(churn$Churn.)) {
  if(churn$State[i]== "CT" | churn$State[i]== "DE"| churn$State[i]== "FL" | churn$State[i]== "GA" | churn$State[i]== "IN" | churn$State[i]== "ME" | churn$State[i]== "MD" | churn$State[i]== "MA" |churn$State[i]== "MI" |churn$State[i]== "NH" |churn$State[i]== "NJ" | churn$State[i]== "NY" |churn$State[i]== "NC" | churn$State[i]== "OH" |churn$State[i]== "PA" |churn$State[i]== "RI" |churn$State[i]== "SC" | churn$State[i]== "VT" | churn$State[i]== "VA" |churn$State[i]== "DC" | churn$State[i]== "WV" ) {
    churn$state.cat.east[i]<-1
  } else {
    churn$state.cat.east[i]<-0
  }
}

for (i in 1:length(churn$Churn.)) {
  if(churn$State[i]== "AL" | churn$State[i]== "AR" | churn$State[i]== "IL" | churn$State[i]== "IA" | churn$State[i]== "KS" | churn$State[i]== "KY" | churn$State[i]== "LA" | churn$State[i]== "MN" | churn$State[i]== "MS" | churn$State[i]== "MO" | churn$State[i]== "NE" | churn$State[i]== "ND" | churn$State[i]== "OK" | churn$State[i]== "SD" | churn$State[i]== "TN" | churn$State[i]== "TX" | churn$State[i]== "WI" ) {
    churn$state.cat.central[i]<-1
  } else {
    churn$state.cat.central[i]<-0
  }
}
```

This is my first post on here so hopefully I have everything I need & thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you need `with(churn,as.integer( State %in% c("CT", "DE", "FL", ...)))`  The `...` represents all those elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this in 2 lines, using ifelse & %in% operator :

```
#FIRST STATEMENT

east <- c("CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "IN", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "NH", "NJ", "NY", "NC", "OH", "PA", "RI", "SC", "VT", "VA", "DC", "WV")
churn$state.cat.east <- ifelse(churn$State %in% east,1,0)
```

Repeat the same for central values

```
#2ND STATEMENT

central <- c("AL" , "AR" , "IL" , "IA" , "KS" , "KY" , "LA" , "MN" , "MS" , "MO" , "NE" , "ND" , "OK" , "SD" , "TN" , "TX" , "WI")
churn$state.cat.central <- ifelse(churn$State %in% central,1,0)
```

Hope this will helps

Gottavianoni

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to use the inbuilt data available in `R`

```
#Sample data
churn <- data.frame(state=c('CA', 'NY', 'TX', 'CA', 'TX'), stringsAsFactors = F)

#map each state to it's division using inbuilt data
data(state)
churn$state_division <- sapply(churn$state, function(x) state.division[which(state.abb==x)])

#dummy code the new column created using above mapping
library(dummies)
churn <- dummy.data.frame(churn, names="state_division", sep = "-")
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I did not see that I could accept an answer - thanks for the lesson!

Comment: Glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

We can do this without `ifelse` as `as.integer` coerces to binary

```
churn$state.cat.east <- with(churn,as.integer( State %in% c("CT", "DE", "FL", ...)))

churn$state.cat.central <- with(churn,as.integer( State %in% c("AL" , "AR",  ...)))
```

NOTE: The `...` refers to other states

---

If we need to create for all the regions

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
state.region %>% 
      unique %>% 
      as.character %>% 
      set_names(.) %>%
      map_df(~ as.integer(setNames(state.region, state.abb)[churn$State] %in% .x) )  %>%
      bind_cols(churn, .)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
churn <- data.frame(State = sample(state.abb, 100, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```